# How to show the selected multiple values in select_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

i have used select_tag for multiple select

```
<%= select_tag "gen", "<option>ACT</option><option>ADV</option><option>ANI</option>
<option>MYS</option><option>WES</option><option>WAR</option><option>THR</option>
<option>SUSP</option><option>ROM</option>".html_safe, :multiple => "multiple" %>
```

I have got this json with selected values, so i need to show these JSON values as selected values
    **gen"=>["ROM", "SUS", "ADV", "THR", "ACT"]**

How to do this via loop?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like

```
<% @gen = ["ROM", "SUS", "ADV", "THR", "ACT"] %>
<%= select_tag "gen", options_for_select(@gen), :multiple => true %>
```

You will get the output like

[image]

Comment: BUt how i give the other options here, i mean
<%= select_tag "gen", options_for_select("ROR", "SAD"),@date["gen"] :multiple => true %>

can i use like that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I added an image in my post please look at it.

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is, in this @gen array is my selected values, so when i show the dropdown, i need to add other options, which i want to select, along with that selected values